# Listening events on div's created on the fly

Tags: javascript, jquery, onclick

I make some post request to create some divs, on which I listen to click events to trigger events. Leet's take these newly created divs '.mydiv', I can't use $('#mydiv').on('click'..) because it is created on the fly, so I use

```
$(document).click(".mydiv", function(){
            //triggers some events
        });
```

But now $(this) refers to the 'document' object, so I can't get the divs that was clicked on and trigger the related event. How can I do that ?

Edit : it seems quite interesting since first I call a function that creates thoses divs and this is in this very function that I call the click listener. In these conditions : $( document ).on( "click" , ".mydiv",...) doesn't work. But when the latter is put directly inside the html page, it works jsut fine. (So at least it is not a jquery version problem)

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).on("click", ".mydiv", function(){
        //triggers some events
});
```

http://api.jquery.com/on/

**Read the `Direct and delegated events` part**

```
//  doc or Parent   |    event   |  dyn. created el 
$(    document    ).on( "click"  ,     ".mydiv",      function(){
        //triggers some events
});
```

Comment: Sure I tried this but I always get this message : Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'on'

Comment: @Newben than use an updated version of jQuery. If that's not an option look at the docs for `.live()` methods

Comment: Whats the jQuery version? If it's too old *(<1.7)* to support .on and you can't update it, check .delegate() or .live() at the jquery docs.

Comment: ok, but it seems quite interesting since I call a function that creates thoses divs and in the same function I call the click listener. In these conditions : $(    document    ).on( "click"  ,     ".mydiv",... doesn't work . But when the latter is put directly inside the html page, it works jsut fine. So it is not a jquery version problem

Comment: @Newben just put the clicks function outside the AJAX or whatever function you have

Comment: yep done, I just tried to understand what was going on when put inside the ajax request :)

Answer (score 0):

also you can try:

```
$(".mydiv").live("click", function(){
            //triggers some events
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

JQuery has a method to bind events on selectors in this type of situations.

```
.live('event', 'handler to be executed') : Attach an event handler for all elements which match the current selector, now and in the future.
```

check-it-out this fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/ff5UJ/